# How to install wall mount corner sink?

Tags: walls, sink, mount

I'm installing a sink in a 3x4 powder room. There's no room for pedestal or legs, so it must be a wall mount. The [chosen sink](https://www.lowes.ca/bathroom-sinks/cheviot-1349-wh-1-corner-corner-wall-mountvessel-sink_g1548653.html?searchTerm=wall-mount-sink-hardware) has no overflow. I'm in Toronto, Canada.

How would I install the sink? What type of bracket? hinges? And plumbing pipe?

[image: Mounting point of sink]

[image: Sink approximately in place]

[image: Bathroom layout]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Nice pictures, but I had to reformat your question to make it a bit more intelligible.

Comment: How to mount it and how to plumb it are two very different questions. Edit to ask just one at a time, please.

Answer (score 2):

The arched notches in the rear skirt are intended to accept heavy bolts with rubber pads and washers.

1. Be sure that you have solid backing where the bolts will need to go. Install two-by lumber, wide face forward, between studs where needed. Be sure they're well anchored.
2. Finish your room. Paint should be complete and well cured.
3. Install the sink by carefully locating the bolts to align with the sink notches. I'd put rubber or plastic sleeves over 7/16" bolts, and use neoprene rubber and stainless steel fender washers to secure to the inside face of the sink skirt. Leave the bolts about 1/4" loose when hanging the sink, the snug them slightly against the skirt. The bolts should be piloted properly and extend at least 2" into the wall.
4. Optionally caulk along the wall. Use the smallest bead necessary to create a good seal and nice appearance. An acrylic with silicone should last well and is paintable.
5. If the drain assembly that comes with your faucet doesn't work out, look for a standard 1-1/4" assembly with full-length threads. Otherwise it's a typical P-trap installation. That's well covered in other questions on SE and throughout the internet.

[Product brochure](http://www.cheviotproducts.com/_files/Content/Line%20Drawings/bathroom%20sinks/over%20counter%20&%20wall%20mount%20sinks/cheviot+1349+corner+sink+10apr14.pdf)

Comment: If you have a lavatory w/o overflow hole and tube, does the 'dome drain' somehow protect from overflow?

Comment: Do you mean lag screws with heads accessible from outside? Or do you mean studs that have a lag screw on one end (to go into 2 x frame) and machine threads on the other end to hold a washer and nut? There is also the possibility of a sleeve that would screw into a hole in the 2 x frame and a machine bolt which would thread into that. I am surprised the mfgr Cheviot do not supply mounting hardware. How does a 'dome drain' work?

Comment: I'd keep it simple and use lags. Dual-thread bolts are certainly another option. Don't know anything about dome drains, but I'm not sure it's necessary. In 20 years of home ownership I've never had need for an overflow drain.